# How to rotate AlertDialog in the program?

Tags: android

My `activity` is in landscape mode. That is my intention and I like to keep in landscape. So all `AlertDialog` or Toast come out in `landscape`. For this case, I like to rotate `AlertDialog` 90 deg in the program, how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: I do not understand. Why you manually rotate it?

Comment: No in the Manifest, I set the activity to be in landscape. But those AlertDialog, I like to show in portrait.

Comment: So you have a landscape Activity but wants to show AlertDialog in portrait?

Comment: yes. I like to show only AlerDialog in portrait.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this layout to custom your dialog : 
https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout

[image]

Comment: It works with text and buttons, but spinners still remain previous rotation

Answer (score 0):

This is something that could be done with a lot of complicated code, but would be quite confusing to the user, as he would have to rotate his device to the read and react to the dialog.

Comment: no my application uses OpenCV's bridging activity to show camera images. Then activity is in landscape for but it shows images in portrait. So the use seed the things in portrait already, just that programming setting is in landscape to have larger image. So I need to make all other things to be in portrait.

Comment: If you use a custom Alert Dialog View, you can set the orientation to be whatever you want. See this click to make a custom one: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/